# Issue after Android 14 launched stopped app running on lower devices (App not installed as package appears to be invalid)

Tags: android, gradle

I am facing an issue on running app on devices after android 14 has arrived.
I have already gone through google docs [Set up the Android 14 SDK](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/14/setup-sdk) by referring this app is installing in emulator and can able to run on connected device on debug mode but not able run debug apk or signed apk on the physical of the devices(On Installing apk a popup came up "App not installed as package appears to be invalid").[image]

tool.build:gradle is above is above 7.0.0

```
    android {
    compileSdkPreview "UpsideDownCake"
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 33
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}
```

Following are the changed I have made on app.gradle file

Comment: i chnaged   targetSdkPreview   "UpsideDownCake" but now get error like there was a problem parsing package did you solve your issue ?

Answer (score 1):

As usual a preview version can only run on an OS of the same version.

That probably only an emulator can provide.